# Haskell Cabal: Mysterious missing or recursive dependencies

Tags: linux, haskell, installation, cabal

I try to install the `jmacro` package. 
It builds perfectly, and there are absolutely no issues.

However, when I want to use it or install packages like `happstack-jmacro`, which depend on jmacro, I get error messages like this:

```
<command line>: cannot satisfy -package-id jmacro-0.5.2-71bd40707d94b0e8eb6e70515ff6a5f4: 
    jmacro-0.5.2-71bd40707d94b0e8eb6e70515ff6a5f4 is unusable due to missing or recursive dependencies:
      haskell-src-meta-0.5-4bf46b12fb313927e18a04de209944de template-haskell-2.5.0.0-f0b857ddb066aae09d974e610edd228f
    (use -v for more information)
```

There are absolutely no recursive or missing dependencies. Is this a bug?

I am using `template-haskell-2.5.0.0` (because the newer versions don't build) and `haskell-src-meta-0.5`. GHC is 7.0.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, solved it myself:

There is a bug and `template-haskell-2.5.0.0` was installed in the system directory of cabal, as well as in my user directory.

When I forcedly unregistered `template-haskell` in my user directory, everything was fine.

Answer (score 11):

Looks like your packages are broken. `ghc-pkg check` might complain about some packages; if it does, you could `ghc-pkg unregister <pkg>` all of them. Otherwise, the best thing is probably to start afresh: save your `~/.cabal/config` file, get rid of `~/.ghc` and `~/.cabal`, and reinstall `cabal-install`.

Cabal problems like this are fairly common, so you might want to look into mitigating the pain with [cabal-dev](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cabal-dev).