# Persistent modules not found

Tags: haskell, persistent

I'm trying to use http://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-1.2.3.0, but after installing it through "cabal install persistent", ghc doesn't find its exposed-modules:

```
Prelude> import Database.Persist.Types

<no location info>:
    Could not find module `Database.Persist.Types'
    It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package.
```

And ghc-pkg works fine:

```
$ ghc-pkg find-module Database.Persist.Types
/var/lib/ghc/package.conf.d
/home/apsk/.ghc/x86_64-linux-7.6.3/package.conf.d
   persistent-1.2.3.0
```

Am I missing something or is this just a bug with cabal/persistent/ghc? My ghc is 7.6.3, btw.

Also, I've tried with no effect: "ghc-pkg recache"; "ghc-pkg check"; installing previous version; reinstalling with and without "sudo" and/or "--global".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check that you're not using sandboxes, cabal-dev, hsenv, anything else that can influence ghc in looking for dependencies. Make sure you're using ghc/ghci, and not any wrappers, and that ghc/ghci are not aliased to anything in your shell.
2. Try to specify the package-db explicitly:

   ```
   ghci -package-db /home/apsk/.ghc/x86_64-linux-7.6.3/package.conf.d
   ```
3. If you launch ghci with `-v`, it'll print the (caches of) databases it looks at, like this:

   ```
   % ghci -v 
   GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
   Glasgow Haskell Compiler, Version 7.6.3, stage 2 booted by GHC version 7.4.2
   Using binary package database: /opt/ghc763/lib/ghc-7.6.3/package.conf.d/package.cache
   Using binary package database: /home/feuerbach/.ghc/i386-linux-7.6.3/package.conf.d/package.cache
   ```

   Make sure that the database which has persistent is listed there.

Comment: Thanks, the trouble was in multiple cabals.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully helpful to someone. Using `ghci -v` I looked to see if persistent was there, and saw this:

```
package persistent-2.0.8-cec952b1a61645f47dbec3b0b0cbcef4 is unusable due to missing or recursive dependencies:  aeson-0.8.0.0-1bd8b5254a1dd30c0fe6acc346ad7de7 attoparsec-0.12.1.2-48393fcdbcf426085b696dc4409d9270 conduit-1.2.0.2-39f9cd0430ed7b7f4306899cbeb1ed83 monad-logger-0.3.7.2-3e6a80e9b3adf31497ff04514bdf2919 resource-pool-0.2.3.0-c02186641e7173f72887d5e65a646ac1 scientific-0.3.3.1-13e0eefbd7215e4503420c3d0a6fdb82 unordered-containers-0.2.5.0-147c3bb8f4a2da7d753455e75af30b92
```

So I looked around on SO (saw this: [Haskell Cabal: Mysterious missing or recursive dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725378/haskell-cabal-mysterious-missing-or-recursive-dependencies)) but didn't find a great answer. I did find a good one [here](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/beginners/2010-September/005181.html) though:

> $ `ghc-pkg list Cabal`

Which revealed I had 2 goddamn cabals! One in user and one in global. Ugh. So I was able to do `ghc-pkg unregister --user Cabal-1.18.1.3 --force` to get rid of the old one. Then `cabal install cabal` automatically went for 1.20, implicitly into user without any flag (the alternate would be `--global`).

Answer (score 0):

The problem only occurs in GHCi, right? Have you restarted GHCi since installing `persistent`? (Maybe there's another way to get GHCi to pick up newly installed packages, but I'm not aware of it.

Comment: Nope, the problems affects both ghc and ghci (even after restarting).